# Discord bot in Python, counting messages from a user

Tags: python, bots, discord

I am currently trying to make a bot with python that gathers statistics from a channel on a server. I want to see how many messages a user has sent in a certain channel. Currently my code looks like this:

```
if message.content.startswith('!stat'):
        mesg = await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Calculating...')
        counter = 0
        async for msg in client.logs_from(message.channel, limit=9999999):
            if msg.author == message.author:
                counter += 1
        await client.edit_message(mesg, '{} has {} messages in {}.'.format(message.author, str(counter), message.channel))
```

This basically does what I want, however the process to calculate all the messages is painfully slow. Is there another method of achieving the same results but with a faster response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could:

- Lower the `limit` when you use `client.logs_from`. You could also leave the limit out, since the bot is most likely trying to get messages that don't exist.
- Interact with the user every x messages. Example:

  ```
  counter = 0
  repeat = 0
  for x in range(0, 4): # Repeats 4 times
      async for msg in client.logs_from(message.channel, limit=500):
          if msg.author == message.author:
              counter += 1
      repeat += 1
  await client.send_message(message.channel, "{} has {} out of the first {} messages in {}".format(message.author, str(counter), 500*repeat, message.channel))
  ```

And it would return something like this:

```
User has 26 out of the first 500 messages in channel
User has 51 out of the first 1000 messages in channel
```

discord.py API reference: http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.logs_from